# Specifying marker type *and* size in a 'scatter' call

Tags: matlab

From the documentation of the scatter command, it seems that markers can be specified in their type or in their size, but not in both, depending on which syntax is used to call the function. Indeed, there is no specific MarkerSize property to this command.

How can I specify the markers' type and size simultaneously, in the same scatter command, or what is an easy workaround if it cannot be done with one command?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) lists `scatter(___,mkr)`, which indicates that `mkr` can be added to any of the previous function signatures including `scatter(x,y,sz)`. Did you try this and get incorrect results?

Comment: See also the [corresponding example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#btrli6p-1_1)...

Comment: Sorry about that, it was indeed clear from the documentation, I was just blindly looking for mkr and sz in the same call but overlooked the __ part, which I now understand refers to any string of preceding input arguments. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `'SizeData'` propery, described in the [scatter properties](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.scatter-properties.html) doc. So the command becomes

```
scatter(X,Y, 'Marker', '*', 'SizeData', 100);
```

You can also save the handle to the scatter object:

```
s = scatter(X,Y);
s.Marker = '*';
s.SizeData = 50;
```

Comment: Many thanks! I had not read the documentation properly, it seems... :(